# Wifi not being detected RTL8723BS , but bluetooth works

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 to breathe new life into my 2 in 1 acer aspire switch one 10 (SW1-011). Everything seems to work properly (with a few minor exceptions) but the real problem is that the wifi card is not being detected.

The model is RTL8723BS, which includes both bluetooth and wifi, working on a SDIO interface as far as I know. The weird thing is that bluetooth works correctly, but the wifi interface is not even listed anywhere.

*iwconfig* shows "no wireless extensions"

*rfkill list all* shows only bluetooth

*sudo lshw -C network* shows only an ethernet interface

There is no physical switch for wireless nor bluetooth, neither a BIOS option. Secure boot is disabled.

I looked at available drivers, but apparently the only one that seemed to be working has been merged into the kernel a while ago and the repository has since then been archived: https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs

I honestly don't know what to do to fix this, any help is welcome.

```
$ dmesg | grep -i rtl
[    6.893883] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[    6.898197] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    6.898202] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_fw.bin
[    6.901274] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_config-OBDA8723.bin
[    6.925627] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 64, total sz 24508
[    7.847984] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x365d462e
```

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -i rtl` show? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 added to question

Comment: It doesn't look to be detected.

Comment: Do you have the /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin file on your system? I'd expect a "loading" message for that file, not the "fw version" you have.

Comment: All messages are related to BT that is working.

Comment: @ubfan1 I do actually, as well as rtl8723bs_bt.bin and rtl8723bs_wowlan.bin

Comment: Is my system picking up the wrong adapter (rtl8723bs_fw.bin), which excludes the wifi from the network card? If that's the case, how do I force the use of the correct one?

Comment: Which kernel are you using?  I did have trouble on 5.5 with my 8723bs, but 5.7 worked fine.

Comment: @ubfan1 I'm on 5.4, I could try to update it (never did it before) and let you know

Comment: @ubfan1 updated to kernel 5.8, but no luck, same problem